# iOS runtime: when doing code module isolation, why protocol OK, method list not OK?

Tags: ios, swift, runtime

when doing code module isolation ( a little like subprojects ) ,

There are one Main Project and two frameworks. Framework A depends on Framework B.

Main Project has the two framework dependencies, and import Framework A , unimport Framework B.

- Framework A has:

```
public protocol AccountLotus {
     func methodA()
}
```

- Framework B has:

```
class AccountLotusoot: NSObject, AccountLotus {
   func methodA(){}
}
```

in the main project,

with runtime reflection, string `ModeleB.AccountLotusoot` to class (NSObject) and comes an instance casted as `AccountLotus`.

then the instance call `methodA`, and it works well.

`methodA` is implemented in frameworkB, not imported in the main project.

**At the same time:**

the framework A has

```
public class Maid: NSObject{}
```

and the framework B has:

```
extension Maid{
    dynamic func loginServiceName() -> String{
        return "ModeleB.AccountLotusoot"
    }
}
```

in the main project, call `printMethodNamesForClass(cls: Maid.self)`, not OK

The method defined and implemented in framework B is needed.

```
func printMethodNamesForClass(cls: AnyClass) {
    var methodCount: UInt32 = 0
    let methodList = class_copyMethodList(cls, &methodCount)
    if let methodList = methodList{
        let arr = Array(arrayLiteral: methodList)
        for (i, m) in arr.enumerated(){
            let name: String = methodName(m: m.pointee) ?? "Not Known"
            print("#\(i): \(name)")
        }
        free(methodList)
    }
}


func methodName(m: Method) -> String? {
    let sel = method_getName(m)
    let nameCString = sel_getName(sel)
    return String(cString: nameCString)
}
```

The above example and below are both based on runtime, why the second one not OK, and how to solve it.

[code in github](https://github.com/BoxDengJZ/ModuleUnImport/tree/main/two)

Comment: What does "not OK" mean? Can you add more clarifying details on exactly what you're seeing, and how it's different from what you expect?

Comment: And btw, you can conveiently make a native Swift collection from a C pointer and count with `UnsafeBufferPoint(start: methodList, count: Int(methodCount))`. You can use the resulting `UnsafeBufferPoint` with `for` loop, collection methods like `forEach`/`map`, or you can copy it into a native Swift array by wrapping it with `Array(...)`

Comment: There is a large project with many iOS developers. Then we divide the project into many modules. And each developer owns his/her module, and could develop his module independently

Comment: " OK " means Main project has dependency Module B, and not import  Module B, and could get method defined in Module B by runtime.

Comment: "Not Ok" means Main project has dependency Module B, and not import Module B, and failed to get method defined in Module B by runtime

Comment: "And each developer owns his/her module, and could develop his module independently" Are the modules literally 1:1 associated with the developers?

Comment: "Main project has dependency Module B, and not import Module B, and failed to get method defined in Module B by runtime" If a module *doesn't* import another module, all bets are off. If you want to use an API from a module, import it.

Comment: For example, when developing shopping cart , not need to compile video streaming part. Large project compiles slowly. Not nice for team work

Comment: YES,  the modules literally 1:1 associated with the developers. So it's easy to judge his work

Comment: Segmenting by modules with architectural/business-domain significance between them makes sense. Having one a dependency module build when a dependent module needs is is a feature, not a bug. It doesn’t matter how long it does or doesn’t take, it’s something you need. If the dependency changes, you *want* it to be rebuilt when the dependant is built, otherwise you have your app in a stale state.

Comment: “ YES, the modules literally 1:1 associated with the developers. So it's easy to judge his work” this is such a remarkably bad idea, I’m not even sure how to address it to be honest. Why can’t you just assess people’s work from looking at their code reviews, or their authorship history in git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Project has dependency B, and not import module B.

Then the project want to use class defined B, it must be **promise**

- The project has dependency A, and import models A.

The project know the protocol defined in module A.

- The promise is that there must be a class in module B , which name is the protocol's name ( in A ) + C
- class aid (the protocol's name + C), must provide a method to show the service provider class's name.
- We can know all user's module by machO
- then combine every user module name with class aid's name, to try if it could be initiated.
- if the aid class could be initiated, then call the service class name provide method.
- finally, you got the module name + "." + service class name , dynamically